# How to search Equidistant character of a word from a nsmutable array of set of characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsmutablearray

I am new to iOS and need some help. 
I am working on a project,
where i need to do a search in a nsmutable array which hold thousands of character which combination of different as well as same characters and i need to do a search of any word and if word found it should be the set equidistant.As a example. Suppose we have set of characters like,

ASDFGFDSRFCGFRDHUJKIHTGRDFESERTGADERWFSGETWGHWGDHWDG`WDGOHARHDK`HRSGDGHSVDFHDJJDKSKWREFGHUJDMSJDHJGDGAFGREFGSDSGDHHDHAHDJSGAFDH`WRODRGK`DHDHDGRGFDCVEDDSGDGDHDHNDHJDJSHGD.

and if we search "WORK" from the above set characters. Then it should show the results as darken the area above.

1. Distance between the word is 2.
2. Distance between the word is 1.

Comment: Is your question about finding an (effective) algorithm for that task, or about how to realize that algorithm in Objective-C for iOS?

Comment: Yes Martin my question is all about the algorithm. I have tried many ways but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Rahul,I come upto this,go further developing and compairing.
This may help you:

```
NSString *characterstring=@"ASDFGFDSRFCGFRDHUJKIHTGRDFESERTGADERWFSGETWGHWGDHWDGWDGOHARHDKHRSGDGHSVDFHDJJDKSKWREFGHUJDMSJDHJGDGAFGREFGSDSGDHHDHAHDJSGAFDHWRODRGKDHDHDGRGFDCVEDDSGDGDHDHNDHJDJSHGD";
NSString *cmpString=@"WORK";
int s;
int p;
for (int j=0; j<cmpString.length; j++) {

    for (int i=0; i<characterstring.length; i++) {
        char b=[characterstring characterAtIndex:i];
        if(b ==[cmpString characterAtIndex:j])
        {
            s=i;
        }
        if (j<cmpString.length-1) {
            if(b ==[cmpString characterAtIndex:j+1])
            {
                p=i;
                if (i+(p-s)<characterstring.length-1) {

                    if([characterstring characterAtIndex:i+(p-s)] ==[cmpString characterAtIndex:j])
                {
                    p=i;
                    NSLog(@"[characterstring characterAtIndex:i+(p-s)]=%c",[characterstring characterAtIndex:i+(p-s)]);
                }
                }
                NSLog(@"====%c",b);
            }

        }


    }
}
```